# Partial process and update in datatable primefaces component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Good evening. I would like to know if there is a way of partially submit just two inputText inside a datatable, it seems it's not possible. The process only works in the entire datatable. Is there a way of grouping the two inputTexts and processing them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In **Primefaces** there is the `partialSbmit`and `process` attributes.

Do the following :

- set `partialSbmit="true"`.
- List the id's of inputTexts you want to process **or** submit all form excluding the id's you don't want to submit using the `process` attribute.

***Additional info :***

- [Primefaces partialSubmit.](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/partialSubmit.xhtml)
- [Primefaces process.](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/process.xhtml)

Comment: Firstly thank you for the answer, but the problem is that in the datatable processing by id does not work, the entire datable is processed instead even if I reference only one Id.

Comment: do you have the form tag wrapping everything correctly ?